# How to implement each iteration of loop in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have loop like below, and by doing so I need to calculate prediction for store = 1 and store = 85, but nevermind... real problem is, why in results data frame: "df_all_2" I have results only for store 1, so my loop works bad, because I need results for store 85 and 1, but I do not see error in this loop, can you help me ?

```
sample_df = data.query('Store in [85, 1]')
Store_list = sample_df["Store"].unique().tolist()

df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"])
df_result.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

for store in Store_list:
    sample_df = data_XGB[data_XGB["Store"]==store]

    ......
    
    test_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_test_XGB)
    train_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_train_XGB)
    
    df_all = pd.concat([test_set, train_set], sort=True)
    df_all = df_all[["Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"]]
    df_all.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_all["Date"] = df_all["Date"].astype("datetime64")
    df_all.sort_values(by="Date", inplace=True)
    df_all.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    
df_all_2 = pd.concat([df_result, df_all], sort=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, but do you have any idea ?

Comment: It seems like you overwrite your df_all in loop, so you only concat your last results (in case of [85,1], that would be results for 1)

Comment: dm2, so how can I change my loop so as to do not overwrite df_all ???

Comment: try to replace the last line in your loop with this: `df_result = df_result.combine_first(df_all)` and then you don't need `df_all_2` -- everything will be in `df_result`

Comment: a11 it does not work, when I use your code with indentation I hve results only for 85 and without indentation I have results only for 1, but I need to have both 1 and 85 :/ other ideas ?